# CSS alignment issue with bootstrap on mobiles

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on http://www.inboundio.com and is using bootstrap for styling, while checking it on mobiles, I noticed the top menu link is overlapping another image (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNJ8s.png), how can I fix this (the dashboard link doesn't look responsive) ?

Here is the HTML code

```
<a href="/dashboard" class="btn btn-success pull-right login-btn">Dashboard</a>
<div class="top-menu pull-right  home-menu" id="main-menu">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="/features">Features</a></li>
    <li><a href="/plans">Pricing</a></li>
    <li><a href="/demo">Demo</a></li>    
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
body.frontend .header .top-menu {
margin-top: 5px;
padding: 5px 10px;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: 140px;
}

.nav {
margin-left: 0;
margin-bottom: 20px;
list-style: none;
}

.pull-right {
float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove `position:absloute` from `body.frontend .header .top-menu` in your css

```
body.frontend .header .top-menu {
margin-top: 5px;
padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

Comment: margin-left: 140px, not is flexible. maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Yes. remove position absolute.

Comment: @AntonioM.Mérida, Abdul and David, Thanks guys, I will push the code on the server and verify it on mobile resolution. For the time being, accepting the answer, will come back and upvote it too.